# How to find the brightest pixel?

Tags: python, raster, qgis-3, raster-calculator

How can I find the brightest (with the highest value) pixel of a raster in QGIS using the calculator of raster or python console?

Comment: Have you tried something like `("my_layer@1" = MAX("my_layer@1")) * "my_layer@1"` ?

Comment: Yes, but into raster calculate formula "MAX("my_layer@1")"  throws an error.

Comment: @MichaelLarshin, could you paste in the error text or provide a screenshot?

Comment: Answer the Question this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345419/find-most-contrast-pixel-on-raster-in-certain-range-of-pixels-around-it/345434#345434