# Find most contrast pixel on raster in certain range of pixels around it?

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel

How to assign to each pixel of a raster value of the biggest difference between values of all pixels around it to a mask on 1 picture (red pixels and everything that after them is not included, black pixels and everything that inside of them are included).

Here is an example of how it works on 2 picture. I wrote such pseudo-code with Python assuming that as input i get list with all closest pixels using as a Central pixel lower left a corner 2 pictures of the. I do not understand how this can be transformed into a script for QGIS or Raster Calculator.

I tried in R the neighbour's module, but every time I set a radius greater than or less than 3 it throws an error. Also, you can take pixels not only for this mask but also for a circular radius of 128 meters. (For images of Landsat with a spatial resolution of 30x30). With what should I implement this?

```r
near_pixels_list = [4,
                    1, 3, 3, 5,
                    8, 4, 1, 3,
                    0, 0, 7, 7,
                    4, 3, 0, 2, 1]
center_pixel = 4
output = max(list(map(lambda x: max(center_pixel, x) - min(center_pixel, x), near_pixels_list)))
```

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Comment: Sorry, I'm from Russia, that's why my English is so bad. I would be very grateful if edit grammar and everything else.

Comment: Don't worry for your english but please translate the title of your question, you will be more likely to get answer with a clear title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you first need Maximum and Minimum values from focal statistics in the 128m-radius window.

Only tool which supports circle window (as far as I know) is SAGA **Residual analysis** tool in `Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Geostatistics`. Settings are:

- Search Mode: `[1] circle`
- Radius (Cells) : `4` ( 4 * 30m = 120m, which is equivalent to your 128m radius)
- Include Center Cell: Leave it on (it does not work... and has no effect on the result)
- Distance Weighting: `[0] no distance weighting`

You will have many outputs, but you just need Maximum and Minimum. Then subtract Minimum from Maximum raster to get the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works, but 3 pixels(120 meters) is not equal to 128 meters radius, so I need that between the center pixel and the capture pixel could fit 2 pixels diagonally.